# Multiple transactions recorded against contribution using webform

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm, contributions

I am using webform_civicrm to allow users to register for memberships. I changed the default payment method from **credit card to invoice**.
As a result of which now multiple transactions are being recorded against the contact.

**Transactions recorded with invoice as default payment method:**
[image]

**Transactions recorded with credit card as default payment method:**
[image]

**Payment methods**
[image]

Please note that I tested with latest civicrm as well and the behaviour is stil the same.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of where you change Payment Method from Credit Card to Invoice?

Comment: Thanks @KarinG-SemperIT, Added the screenshot for payment method screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a known issue which recently got fixed in webform civicrm. Can you try applying the patch https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/180 or use the latest 7.x version from github and see if it fixes this problem for you?

Comment: I was going to point him to that but am really confused how Invoice is a payment method? That sounds like a custom config possibly custom code?

Comment: Hey @KarinG-SemperIT, jitendra - fuzion
Yes, Invoice is a custom payment method and the patch sorts out my issue.
Thanks a ton!!